# hard brick? [asus zenfone 5 - lollipop]

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking, asus-zenfone-5

I have a problem with my asus zenfone 5 (root). I think it's hard bricked. I will explain better, yesterday I did a restore to "clean" the system, while restoring freezes, then I try to boot into recovery mode. I long ago, installed a custom recovery, the fact is that by inserting the `recovery.img` and trying to start it from the custom recovery. I get errors and does not install, so start in droidboot mode to adjust all manualmente by pc (GNU / linux), with `fastboot flash recovery.img`, but when I have to do the last step described by driving mistake.

Now I do not have a chance to get more in recovery mode, in fact, when I press `power` + `vol` appears the Android logo with red exclamation point, if I try to start it normally there is a loading of the asus logo with the infinite wheel, but when there is asus adb logo detects it, it just says chen is not "authorized", the phone has to be thrown away? There are hardware / software solutions ?
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The BEST way to unbrick an Android device is to use Odin. This exe program has saved many android users from having to buy another phone. Although I am not a pro with Odin, try looking up on Google about how to flash with Odin. Odin supports both Windows and MAC but windows is better.

Did you ever make a backup of your ROM? Unless you didn't have a custom recovery, making a Nandroid backup is extremely important.

If your device is hard-bricked with no backup, then you will need to download your original STOCK ROM (which can be found on the internet), and flash it through odin.

Also you will need a PIT file for your phone. PIT files tell Odin where to correctly place the files when flashing.

You can obtain the correct PIT file by looking up your phone model and then add "PIT file" along with the model.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot , unfortunately I do not have no windows pc at home , I just pc with freebsd and gnu / linux , I will assess to take it into a repair shop , thank you so much